# Not able to initialize objects in each array index

Tags: java, arrays, object

I'm trying to create an array that lets the user input information about a movie

```
public void addMovie() {
  for(int x = 0; x < mlist.length; x++) {
     mlist[x] = new Movies();
     System.out.println("What is the title of the movie? ");
     title = scan.nextLine();
     System.out.println("What is the genre of the movie? ");
     genre = scan.nextLine();
     System.out.println("Who is the director of the movie? ");
     director = scan.nextLine();
     System.out.println("What is the cost of the movie? ");
     cost = scan.nextInt();
  }
}
```

When I compile, it says that

```
mlist[x] = new Movies();
```

constructor Movies in class Movies cannot be applied to given types;

Complete code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Movies
{
   private String title, genre, director;
   private int cost;
   Movies mlist[] = new Movies[5];

   Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

   public Movies(String mtitle, String mgenre, String mdirector, int mcost)
   {
      title = mtitle;
      genre = mgenre;
      director = mdirector;
      cost = mcost;
   }

   public void addMovie()
   {
      for(int x = 0; x < mlist.length; x++)
      {
         mlist[x] = new Movies();
         System.out.println("What is the title of the movie? ");
         title = scan.nextLine();
         System.out.println("What is the genre of the movie? ");
         genre = scan.nextLine();
         System.out.println("Who is the director of the movie? ");
         director = scan.nextLine();
         System.out.println("What is the cost of the movie? ");
         cost = scan.nextInt();
      }
   }


   public String getTitle()
   {
      return title;
   }
   public String getGenre()
   {
      return genre;
   }
   public String getDirector()
   {
      return director;
   }
   public int getCost()
   {
      return cost;
   }
}
```

Comment: What is the constructor for `Movies` and what is the type of `mlist`?

Comment: You're using the default constructor for Movies, since you defined your own (taking more arguments) you are no longer able to use it. You can read in these variables, then call your own constructor passing in these values.

Comment: You also have a serious design problem. Why does a Movie has 5 movies. I would understand if a cinema had 5 movies. But movies don't have movies. And Why is it called "Movies" and not "Movie"?

Comment: Yep it's generally not a good idea to have a class also in charge of instances of the class. Like JB Nizet suggested, to me it makes a lot more sense to have Movie class, and then a list/array of movies in another class.

Comment: It's a Movie with a 5 sequels/prequels :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the function addMovie(), you are taking input from the user and not using using it anywhere. Instead of calling a parameter-less constructor, call the parametrized constructor which you created and pass the input values to this constructor.

Code :

```
public void addMovie() {
    for (int x = 0; x < mlist.length; x++) {
        // Deleted the call to default constructor.
        System.out.println("What is the title of the movie? ");
        title = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("What is the genre of the movie? ");
        genre = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Who is the director of the movie? ");
        director = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("What is the cost of the movie? ");
        cost = scan.nextInt();
        // Added this code
        mlist[x] = new Movies(title,genre,director,cost);
    }
}
```

This should resolve the error .